# Serving application with wrong mime type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, firefox, mime, mime-types

My MVC 2 application seems to be serving pages as application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml in Firefox Beta 10.

Works fine in other browsers.

Any ideas? Is this a bug i FF4 and should I just ignore it?

Comment: Is this cassini/development server?  If so I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: I preproduction enviroment. Cloning a working request from FF and changing useragent to: User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0b10) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0b10 triggers the behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were running **WURFL** (http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) - which wasnt quite ready to handle Beta 10

Answer (score 2):

We are having the same trouble with our asp.net 2.0 WebForms Using 51Degrees.mobi and WURFL. Anyway, upgrading to the latest version of 51Degrees solved our problem. We also made sure that Firefox 4.0 was in our web_browsers_patch.xml file.